# Why loading Facebook images suddenly became so slow

Tags: android, facebook, android-networking

I have an android app that worked well. Users are signing through Facebook.  I have a `recyclerview` showing lists of users' profile photos.  I don't know what happened because suddenly this list loads very slowly: **up to 20 seconds for only 10 photos**.

This is the URL I'm using: `http://graph.facebook.com/<fbId>/picture?type=square`

I really don't know what happened. I tried to fetch with small size `100X100` and I tried not using `Picasso` for loading and develop my own async task... But this is not the problem.  It is somehow Facebook.

Maybe something changed in android after certain update regarding the network. But can't find any solution for it.

I have the same code in iOS and it still works there.  The android version is running for a much longer time than iOS so maybe Facebook is limiting access.  But even so, how can they?  It is access through a URL. I'm really out of ideas.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried testing with a different url for the images to rule out server congestion issues?

Comment: Yes.. I've made a list of random online images and it works good as usual..

Comment: It looks like there is an opened issue on [Facebook about it](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/294867958075910/?disable_redirect=0)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? It's not resolved yet and noone in Facebook cares about it.

Comment: No. And it is kind of killed our App..